# breeze observableArray binding - are properties observable?

Tags: breeze

I have a viewmodel which consists of a list(foreach loop) of DoctorPrices and when clicking on an item in the list it open up a CRUD form on the side. However when i update the values on the CRUD the observableArray that is bound to the foreach is not refreshing? (although the values are updates in the DB correctly)

From my data access module i call the following query.

```
function getDoctorServices(doctorId) {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery
         .from('DoctorPrices')
         .where('DoctorID', 'eq', doctorId).orderBy('ListOrder');
    return manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
}
```

In my viewmodel i have the following code:

```
this.services = ko.computed(function() {
            return doctorServices.getDoctorServices(doctorList.viewModel.instance.currentDoctorID());
});
```

services is bound using a foreach loop (*not posting here as the code is simple and works*)

When i click on a one of the DoctorPrices it gets the data as follows and places it in an observable:

```
this.selectedPrice = function (data, event) {
            self.currentService(data);
            self.showEdit(true);

        };
```

I then bind selectPrice to a simple form that has the properties on it to be modified by the user. I then call manager.SaveChanges().

This results in the following problem: **the value is being updated correctly but the GUI / Original List that is bound in the foreach is not being updated**? Are the properties in breeze not observables? What is the best way to work with something like this.

I thought of a workaround and changing the code with something like this:

```
doctorList.viewModel.instance.currentDoctorID.subscribe(function() {
            self.services([]);
            self.services(doctorServices.getDoctorServices(doctorList.viewModel.instance.currentDoctorID()));
        });
```

But i feel that clearing the array in that way is sloppy and not the right way of doing things specially with long lists.

Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to bind observableArray properties properly so they are updated?

Additional code my VM Component:

```
      function services() {
        var self = this;
        this.showForm = ko.observable(false);
        this.currentService = ko.observable();
        this.services = ko.observableArray(doctorServices.getDoctorServices(doctorList.viewModel.instance.currentDoctorID()));
        this.title = ko.observable();


        doctorList.viewModel.instance.currentDoctorID.subscribe(function() {
            self.services([]);
            self.services(doctorServices.getDoctorServices(doctorList.viewModel.instance.currentDoctorID()));
            self.showDetails(false);
        });


        this.show = function (value) {
            self.showForm(value);
        };


        this.showDetails = ko.observable(false);

        this.addNewService = function() {
            self.currentService(doctorServices.createService(doctorList.viewModel.instance.currentDoctorID()));
            console.log(self.currentService().entityAspect.entityState);
            self.showDetails(true);
        };

        this.showDelete = ko.computed(function() {
            if (self.currentService() == null)
                return false;
            else if (self.currentService().entityAspect.entityState.isDetached()) {
                self.title('Add new service');
                return false;
            } else {
                self.title('Edit service');
                return true;
            }
        });

        this.deleteService = function() {
            self.currentService().entityAspect.setDeleted();
            doctorServices.saveChanges();
            doctorList.viewModel.instance.currentDoctorID.notifySubscribers();
        };

        this.closeDetails = function () {
            doctorServices.manager.rejectChanges();
            doctorList.viewModel.instance.currentDoctorID.notifySubscribers();
            self.showDetails(false);
        };
        this.selectService = function (data, event) {
            self.currentService(data);
            self.showDetails(true);
        };
        this.saveChanges = function () {
            console.log(self.currentService().entityAspect.entityState);
            if (self.currentService().entityAspect.entityState.isDetached()) {
                doctorServices.attachEntity(self.currentService());
            }
            console.log(self.currentService().entityAspect.entityState);
            doctorServices.saveChanges();
            doctorList.viewModel.instance.currentDoctorID.notifySubscribers();
            self.currentService.notifySubscribers();
            self.showDetails(true);
        };


    }
    return {
        viewModel: {
            instance: new services()
        },
        template: servicesTemplate,
    };
```

Below is my Breeze Data Class:

```
 define('data/doctorServices', ['jquery', 'data/dataManager', 'knockout','mod/medappBase', 'breeze', 'breeze.savequeuing'], function ($, manager, ko,base, breeze, savequeuing) {
var services = ko.observableArray([]);


return {
    attachEntity:attachEntity,
    getServices: getServices,
    services: services,
    manager:manager,
    getDoctorServices: getDoctorServices,
    getServiceById: getServiceById,
    createService:createService,
    hasChanges: hasChanges,
    saveChanges: saveChanges
};



function getServices() {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("DoctorPrices");
    return manager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {
        services(data.results);
    }).fail(function (data) {
        console.log('fetch failed...');
        console.log(data);
    });;
}



function getDoctorServices(doctorId) {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery
         .from('DoctorPrices')
         .where('DoctorID', 'eq', doctorId).orderBy('ListOrder');
    var set = manager.executeQueryLocally(query);

    return set;
}

function getServiceById(serviceId) {
    return manager.createEntity('DoctorPrice', serviceId);
    //return manager.getEntityByKey('DoctorPrice', serviceId);
}

function handleSaveValidationError(error) {
    var message = "Not saved due to validation error";
    try { // fish out the first error
        var firstErr = error.innerError.entityErrors[0];
        message += ": " + firstErr.errorMessage;
        base.addNotify('error', 'Could not save.', message);
    } catch (e) { /* eat it for now */ }
    return message;
}

function hasChanges() {
    return manager.hasChanges();
}

function attachEntity(entity) {
    manager.addEntity(entity);
}

function createService(doctorId) {
    return manager.createEntity('DoctorPrice', { DoctorPricingID: breeze.core.getUuid(), DoctorID:doctorId }, breeze.EntityState.Detached);

};


function saveChanges() {
    return manager.saveChanges()
        .then(saveSucceeded)
        .fail(saveFailed);

    function saveSucceeded(saveResult) {
        base.addNotify('success', 'Saved.', 'Your updates have been saved.');
    }

    function saveFailed(error) {
        var reason = error.message;
        var detail = error.detail;

        if (error.innerError.entityErrors) {
            reason = handleSaveValidationError(error);
        } else if (detail && detail.ExceptionType &&
            detail.ExceptionType.indexOf('OptimisticConcurrencyException') !== -1) {
            // Concurrency error 
            reason =
                "Another user, perhaps the server, " +
                "may have deleted one or all of the settings." +
                " You may have to restart the app.";
        } else {
            reason = "Failed to save changes: " + reason +
                     " You may have to restart the app.";
        }
        console.log(error);
        console.log(reason);
    }
}
```

});

**Please note this is my frist attempt at both a data class and VM. At the moment i am relying heavily on clearing the array ([]) and using notifySubscribers to make the array refresh** :(

Answer (score 0):

I bet you're missing an observable somewhere. I can't tell because you keep hopping from property to property whose definition is not shown.

For example, I don't know how you defined `this.currentService`.

I'm confused by this:

```
this.services = ko.computed(function() {
        return doctorServices.getDoctorServices(doctorList.viewModel.instance.currentDoctorID());
});
```

Why is it a `ko.computed`? Why not just make it [an observable array](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html).

```
self.service = ko.observableArray();

// ... later replace the inner array in one step ...
self.service(doctorServices.getDoctorServices(
    doctorList.viewModel.instance.currentDoctorID()));
```

I urge you to follow the observability trail, confident that your Breeze entity properties are indeed observable.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. its a computed because currentDoctorID changes in a dropdown which then needs to requiry / filter breeze. I have updated with observable definitions at the top - those are correct or would have thrown an error.

Comment: Thanks after all that posting i think i might have found my error as you correctly pointed out i am declaring service as an observable and not an observable array... So i will have a look at that and change the definition from: this.services = ko.observable() to this.services = ko.observableArray()!! What a rookie mistake! (must have been a late night!)

Comment: Hi Ward. I have tried in vain again, even if i change the observable to an array when i manipulate the underlying data the list is not updated - i think my question is if i run a simple query and bind it to a list, if the underlying cache changes (add new records etc) will the list update automatically? or does one need to requery and repopulate the array?

Comment: **The list should update automatically**. I wish I knew what is going astray in your use case. Can you provide a super simple example of the failure.? It should be stripped to the bone. Put it in a gist or a plunker. Seems to me you'd only need a 2 entity model (Doctor and DoctorPrice) with some phony data to make the case. It doesn't need a server. For inspiration, check out [this KO/Breeze example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9XCdT07m9p7B3ZGhs1hu?p=info) which has no server. It might be a starting place for your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
 vm.selectedPrice  = ko.dependentObservable(function () {

       return doctorServices.getDoctorServices(doctorList.viewModel.instance.currentDoctorID());


    }, vm);
```

vm is ur model on which u applied bindings , try this it will work.